# generating a binary tree from given data in python

Tags: python, binary-tree

i wanted to know how to read values from a list into a binary tree.
i have a triangle like this:

```
         0
       1   2
     3   4   5
   6   7   8   9
```

i have written a class node like this

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,data,left=None,right=None):
        self.data=data
        self.left=left
        self.right=right
```

basically what i want to do is something like this

node(0,node(1),node(2))

i want to make a recursive function that can handle much bigger triangles. Can somehow tell me what i am supposed to do?

edit: quite clearly binary tree is not the way to approach this problem. what i basically want to find out are all the different combination's from top to bottom. like 0,1,3,6   0,2,5,8   etc.

Comment: shouldn't it be tagged a homework?

Comment: What is the list input of the function you want to make, and the expected tree output?

Comment: This looks like functional code. I would capitalize to Node so that it follows the standard for naming a class (right now it looks like a function). What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It's unclear whether that "triangle" is actually a binary tree, because you don't show any of the edges (connections between nodes). Which node is 7's parent? 3? 4? Both? If both, then this isn't a tree.

Comment: I doubt recursion is the way to go here. As far as I understand, you need to process the nodes in a first-in-first-out manner (hint:use a queue). This also does not look like a binary tree - nodes can have two parents.

Comment: i was actually trying to solve a puzzle. what i intended to achieve was to find was all the different combination's from top to bottom like 0,1,3,6     0,2,4,8  etc. binary lists is probably the wrong approach to do this but i wanted to learn how to create trees given a list.
@laurence i did not know that, thank you..

Answer (score 1):

This does sound like homework, so I won't write code, but here are a couple of hints:

1. This could be done even if your triangle were written as a list, like 
   `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
2. Because it seems like this is a full binary tree (assuming your triangle is wrong and the third row is actually supposed to be `3 4 5 6`), you could maintain a `parents` queue whose head is the next parent that needs children.  Note that I am specifically not recommending recursion.

A full binary tree is one where each non-leaf node has exactly two children.  If this is not supposed to be a full binary tree, then there is no deterministic way to interpret the problem (since each of node 1 and 2 could have 1 or 2 children, given your picture).

Comment: i am new to this site so i dont know if help on puzzles from projecteuler are banned, i am sorry if it is. the solution to this problem is available on the pyeuler site, but i could not understand anything.  the structure of the triangle gave me the impression that it could be solved using trees, so i thought of trying out my theory and hit a dead end.

Comment: No, it's not banned.  But the specification of the problem as you have it seems odd.  Do you have a link, or better yet, can you recheck the problem statement and revise?

Answer (score 0):

For such list:

```
a = 'aBCdef'
```

The program below generates the following structure:

```
- a -
- B C
B C -
- d e
d e f
e f -
```

Code (input list is assumed to correspond to a 'complete' triangular):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data,left=None,right=None):
        self.data=data
        self.left=left
        self.right=right

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (
                self.left.data if self.left or '-', 
                self.data, 
                self.right.data if self.right or '-')


nodelist = [Node(c) for c in a]

i,y = 0,1

while True:
    for x in range(y):
        nodelist[i].left = nodelist[i-1] if x!=0 else None
        nodelist[i].right = nodelist[i+1] if x!=y-1 else None
        i+=1
    if i<len(a):
        y+=1
    else:
        break

for n in nodelist:
    print unicode(n)
```