# Create a binary tree from a given list

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, binary-tree

I want to create a binary tree from a given list. How can I go about it?
Suppose,

```
list = [0, 5400, 33735, 2317, 123, 242737, 0, 0, 0, 1368, 43654]
```

is the list I want to create a tree for.

I tried the following code but I am not sure what it is doing.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data
def check():
nodelist = [Node(c) for c in list]

    i,y = 0,len(list)
    while True:
        for x in range(y):
            nodelist[i].left = nodelist[i-1] if x!=0 else None
            nodelist[i].right = nodelist[i+1] if x!=y-1 else None
            i+=1
        if i<len(list):
            y+=1
        else:
            break

    for n in nodelist:
        print unicode(n)
```

Pardon for my weakness in Algorithms. Data Structures really scare me off..

And [generating a binary tree from given data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078669/generating-a-binary-tree-from-given-data-in-python) is where I tried the code from.

Comment: _"I tried the following code but I am not sure what it is doing"_ [a] this code, did you write it or its from some book? [b] what do you _expect_ it to do? What is the output you want?

Comment: nodelist [<custom.binary_tree_preorder.Node instance at 0x03CFCD00>, <custom.binary_tree_preorder.Node instance at 0x03CEEBE8>, <custom.binary_tree_preorder.Node instance at 0x03CEED50>, <custom.binary_tree_preorder.Node instance at 0x03D04530>, <custom.binary_tree_preorder.Node instance at 0x03D045A8>, <custom.binary_tree_preorder.Node instance at 0x03D04800>, <custom.binary_tree_preorder.Node instance at 0x03D04788>, <custom.binary_tree_preorder.Node instance at 0x03D044E0>,.....]
This is what it is printing. I want the list that I have, to be printed in the form of a binary tree.

Comment: What is `Node`, and you are going to have to give _a lot more details_ to go further.

Answer (score 1):

`"I tried the following code but I am not sure what it is doing."` is brilliant. Where did you get that code? What should it do?

Do you want a binary tree or is it a **sorted** binary tree? Should the tree have bounded or minimal depth?

Your algorithm seems to be converting to a double linked list. If my limited experience in python doesn't stop me from noticing a really strange exceptional/border case it's equivalent to:

```
nodelist = [Node(c) for c in list]

for i in range(len(list)):
    if i != 0:
        nodelist[i].left = nodelist[i-1]
    if i != len(list) - 1:
        nodelist[i].right = nodelist[i+1]

for n in nodelist:
    print unicode(n)
```

First block converts the list of numbers to a list of nodes containing the numbers.
Second block runs through the list linking all but the left-most node to its left and all but the right-most to its right.
Last block prints the list of nodes that now form a double linked list.

By the way your double-linked list can be interpreted as unsorted binary tree of **maximal** depth. But in this interpretation "left" is a strangely named reference to the parent, which means that you may be missing an empty reference for each non-existant left child.